# How do I get line number and file name from angular error object?

Tags: angular

I have this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDataSource' of undefined
    at EmptyComponent.push../src/app/empty/empty.component.ts.EmptyComponent.ngOnInit (empty.component.ts:29)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22098)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23362)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23324)
    at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23865)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EmptyComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:9)
    at Object.updateDirectives (core.js:23653)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23306)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23547)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23510)
```

can I extract the line number and file name

empty.component.ts:29 ?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you have at issue in empty.component.ts line 29, the value of `setDataSource` is coming as `undefined`.

Comment: @user123456 What do you mean extract?

Comment: I mean I need only to log file name : empty.component, error number : 29

Comment: console.error(error.fileName, error.lineNumber, ':', error.columnNumber, '\n', error.message, error.rejection); like this

Comment: you can use `error-stack-parser` npm package.

Comment: what it does @micronyks

Comment: It gives you stack related information properly. This might be useful if you just check it out.

Comment: Cannot find name 'ErrorStackParser'.ts(2304)

Comment: I run npm install error-stack-parser

Comment: @micronyks any example

Answer (score 1):

If you already catch this error, you can try to parse e.stack.

```
function getFileNameFromException(e: Error): string {
   const {stack} = e;
   if (!stack) {
      return;
   }
   const match = /.*\n\s*at\s.*\s\((.*\/)*(.*):([\d]*):([\d]*)/.exec(stack);
   if (!match) {
      return;
   }
   return {
      fileName: match[1],
      line: Number(match[2]),
      column: Number(match[3]),
   };
}
```

Comment: I get my-error-handler.ts:16 http://localhost:4200/main.js:1161:23

Comment: I just need 2 var one for file name and another for number

Comment: No problem. Few minutes, i fix it.

Comment: @user123456 try this variant

Comment: can you share your stack?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217888/discussion-between-sviatoslav-miller-and-user123456).

Comment: fir off all  fileName: match[1],
      line: Number(match[2]),
      column: Number(match[3]), not string , change to any then log you get in 0 TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDataSource' of undefined↵    at EmptyComponent.push../src/app/empty/empty.component.ts.EmptyComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:4200/main.js:1161:23"

Comment: You need a string? Why you cant call ```const parsed = getFileNameFromException(e); console.log(parsed.fileName, `${parsed.line}:${parsed:column}`)```?

Comment: got to chat s u advised